# Preventing LVM from accessing "low-level" devices of DRBD

Tags: linux, debian, kvm-virtualization, lvm, drbd

Context:

Active/passive DRBD setup.
KVM VMs on LVM volumes. LVM using `/dev/drbd0` for physical volume and volume group.

During tests of the setup I have:

1. Shut down Secondary node.
2. Rebooted Primary node.

However, a VM that was autostarted after Primary reboot somehow accessed underlying disk (`/dev/sda4`) for `/dev/drbd0`:

```
WARNING: Device mismatch detected for vgr0/r0_wphp which is accessing /dev/sda4 instead of /dev/drbd0.
```

`/dev/sda4` is a device used for `/dev/drbd0`:

```
resource r0 {
        protocol C;
        startup {
                wfc-timeout  15;
                degr-wfc-timeout 60;
        }
        disk {
                on-io-error     detach;
                c-fill-target   10M;
                c-max-rate      700M;
                c-plan-ahead    7;
                c-min-rate      4M;
        }
        net {
                # max-epoch-size  20000;
                max-buffers       36k;
                sndbuf-size       1024k;
                rcvbuf-size       2048k;
                after-sb-0pri    discard-zero-changes;
                after-sb-1pri    discard-secondary;
                after-sb-2pri    disconnect;
                rr-conflict      disconnect;                
        }
        syncer {
                rate                    400M;
                al-extents              6433;
        }
        on NormallySecondary {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/sdc;
                address 10.0.0.1:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
        on NormallyPrimary {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/sda4;
                address 10.0.0.2:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
}
```

After unintended start of `r0_wphp` VM now I have this:

```
% lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk 
├─sda1               8:1    0 46.6G  0 part /
├─sda2               8:2    0 46.6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3               8:3    0  1.7T  0 part 
...
└─sda4               8:4    0  1.8T  0 part 
  └─vgr0-r0_wphp   254:0    0   40G  0 lvm
```

`vgr0-r0_wphp` (LVM volume used by `r0_wphp` VM)  should use volume group `vgr0` that is using `/dev/drbd0` as physical volume, **not `/dev/sda4` directly**.

I *think* this is the reason for DRBD now refusing to start `r0` on my `NormallyPrimary` node:

```
% drbdadm create-md r0
open(/dev/sda4) failed: Device or resource busy

Exclusive open failed. Do it anyways?
[need to type 'yes' to confirm]
```

Certainly `lsof /dev/sda4` does not show anything.

`drbd` service was **not** started automatically on booting `NormallyPrimary` node.

The weird thing is that before tests I **have** configured LVM to ignore `/dev/sda4`:

```
 % egrep '^\s*filter =' /etc/lvm/lvm.conf 
    filter = [ "r|/dev/sda4|" ]
```

After defining this LVM filter, `drbdadm` created `r0` resource without complaints, the DRBD setup was working.

Questions:

1. How can I stop the VM in question from using `/dev/sda4`? I need to re-attach my DRBD resource (`r0`).
2. How can I **prevent** any LVM-backed VMs from trying to access devices underlying `/dev/drbd*` devices even when unintentionally started?

OS and DRBD:

```
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:    9.6
Codename:   stretch

% dpkg -l | grep drbd
ii  drbd-utils                                    8.9.10-2                                    amd64        RAID 1 over TCP/IP for Linux (user utilities)
```

Comment: After changing lvm.conf you must [`update-initramfs`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/initramfs-tools/update-initramfs.8.en.html) and reboot.